# Bash function argument is not working with ranges

Tags: bash, function

I'm trying to make a bash function argument work with ranges.

The following working code which gives the desired results:

```
ddos_attack_mirroring_defense() {
    echo $1;
}
```

ddos_attack_mirroring_defense() Hi NSA

gives:

```
Hi NSA
```

But the following with ranges is not working:

```
ddos_attack_mirroring_defense() {
    printf "regx32%0.s" {1..$1};
}
```

ddos_attack_mirroring_defense 5
returns:

```
regx32
```

instead of:

```
regx32regx32regx32regx32regx32
```

I've tried spaces and other different enclosures such as but they still don't work:

```
$(1) ${1}
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Brace expansion happens before variable expansion. As a result, you can't use variables in ranges, you can only use literals.

See `man bash`:

> The  order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ddos_attack_mirroring_defense() {
     eval printf "regx32%0.s" {1..$1};
}

ddos_attack_mirroring_defense 5
```

Comment: Using `echo` is not really necessary.

Comment: @konsolebox: Thanks! I have removed the echo.

Comment: Using `eval` isn't recommended; the argument that is passed can contain shell syntax, allowing arbitrary code execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Unix utility `seq` to produce ranges of numbers.

```
printf "regx32%0.s" $(seq $1)
```

Comment: Wherever you're running Bash, you'll likely also have `seq`.

Answer (score 0):

You should let the variable expand first before brace expansion. You can use a safe `eval` to fix that:

```
ddos_attack_mirroring_defense() {
    eval "printf 'regx32%0.s' {1..$1}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving this:

```
ddos_attack_mirroring_defense() {
    perl -e "print 'regx32'x$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A safer alternative to using `eval` is

```
ddos_attack_mirroring_defense() {
    printf "regx32"
    for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++)); do
        printf "%0.s" "$i"
    done
}
```